# Running Java program with classpaths

Tags: java, classpath

This is one of my first java codes. Pardon me if the question is too naive.

I have an external jar file, an API. I want to be able to call the methods in this API using a java program. I wrote the following code:

`update.java`:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.io.IOException;
import rediff.inecom.catalog.product.CSVAPI;

class MyFirstClass{
    private final static String api_key = "xyz";
    private final static String path = "/path/to/myfile.csv";

    public void myFunction() {
        CSVAPI cvsapi = new CSVAPI();
        System.out.println(cvsapi);
        try {
            String output = cvsapi.UpdateCSVAPI(api_key,path);
            System.out.println(output);
            System.out.println("Success!");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("catch");
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new MyFirstClass().myFunction();
    }
}
```

I compiled it using the following command:

```
javac -cp vendorcatalogapi.jar update.java
```

I am trying to run it using the following command:

```
java -cp vendorcatalogapi.jar -cp . MyFirstClass
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rediff/inecom/catalog/product/CSVAPI
    at MyFirstClass.myFunction(update.java:12)
    at MyFirstClass.main(update.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rediff.inecom.catalog.product.CSVAPI
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
```

How can I correctly set the classpath while running the Java program?

Comment: Use `java -cp .;vendorcatalogapi.jar MyFirstClass` with windows, `java -cp .:vendorcatalogapi.jar MyFirstClass` with Unix(-like). Just a hint: Give the `.java` files the same name of your java class. It will be much easier for you to find classes.

Comment: Bdw have u set classpath in environment varaibles??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `java` and `javac` commands accept only one `cp` or `classpath` parameter.

If you have multiple classpath elements, you can concatenate them using a separator element which is `';'` on windows and `':'` on unix systems:

```
javac -cp .;vendorcatalogapi.jar update.java
java -cp .;vendorcatalogapi.jar MyFirstClass
```

Answer (score 4):

try executing this way
 in windows

```
java -cp .;path/to/vendorcatalogapi.jar MainClass
```

in linux environment

```
java -cp .:path/to/vendorcatalogapi.jar MainClass
```